# k-means clustering using spark Mlib

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, data-mining, k-means, text-classification

I want to perform K means clustering on the data set like below

(OA,mobileNO,Text are Headers of csv)

**OA|mobileNO|Text**
575756|918050173932|sekhar added a photo. See it at https://fb.com/l/
RM-444555|91879225717|Dominos Buy 1 Pizza & Get 1 free
VM-OLAMNY|919160281882|Added rs.10 in OLA cab ride

like above I have a huge dataset,How can I cluster the data and find hidden patterns in it. (ex: Which OA is sending cab related messages,which OA is sending fb notifications etc.)

I have to get the clusters of OA based on text they are sending like

cluster 1: cab related OA cluster 2 :fb notifications etc

Does K-means clustering works only on numeric data?

Comment: too broad, please be specific with your problem, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried to cluster by taking only text filed. By tokenizing ,stopwords removing, and calculating TF-IDF weights.How can we use TF-IDF weights as input of KMeans.In spark documentation clustering of numeric data is explained.Here I have all text fields.

Comment: kmeans only works with numeric vectors, it's the case for every available framework on the globe

Answer (score 0):

k-means only works reliably on **continuous numerical variables**.

There is a reason for that: on other data, the *mean* is not meaningful, so k-means clusters are not meaningful.

Comment: can you please mention some reference.

Comment: Reference for what? Properties of the *mean* (because that is where the problem is)? Least-squares estimation?

Comment: "k-means only works reliably on continuous numerical variables" from where this is coming. I have used k-means for discrete variables and it worked just fine.

Comment: Have you compared it to other methods? k-means won't "crash", but on such data, ghe result usually is not better than *random* convex partitions. If you present the k-means clustersy and random convex partitions to a user and do an A/B test, the random is just as good.